# how to faster scroll a listview to last item in listview in Winform in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a list view in winform with a list view to scroll to the last item in the list when the new message is coming. 
My problem is that when the message is coming so fast in my client my system is slow and not responding for some time and my mouse arrow changes shape to wheel.

Sample Example:

```
        for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
            listView1.BeginUpdate();
            listView1.Items.Add(a);
            listView1.EnsureVisible(listView1.Items.Count - 1);
            listView1.EndUpdate();
        }
```

**Real Case My client**
This function is call from thread When new message is come. My Clint code is large i only shows this code because this code is used to display a message in list view.
when we comment scroll lines then system performance good when we scroll to last message and when message come **12,000** it slow down the speed.

```
private void HandleNewMsg(string msg)
    {           
        if(chkAppend.Checked)
        {

            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new AppendTextDelegate(HandleNewMsg), new object[] { msg });
            }

            else
            {
                // call here to parse the message
                ShowMessage(ParseMessage(msg));

            }
        }
    }
```

And Show Message Method

```
private void ShowMessage(List<String>MsgReceived){
        listview1.BeginUpdate();
        foreach(var i in MsgReceived)
        {
            listview1.Items.Add(i);

        }
        listView1.EnsureVisible(listView1.Items.Count - 1);
       listview1.EndUpdate();

    }
```

And ParseMessage is

```
private List<String> ParseMessage(String Message){

        List<String> msg=new List<String>();
        msg.Add(Message.Substring(0, 13));// title such as msg received
        msg.Add("Msg Type  " + Message.Substring(41+13 , 4));
        msg.Add("p Code    " + Message.Substring(65 +13, 2));
        msg.Add("*************");
        // and other data in it .
        return msg;
    }
```

How can I make it not hang And Scroll to Last Message?

Comment: The user tends to be grateful getting a break, having to claw through thousands of items can be pretty exhausting.  Create usable UI and you don't have to solve this problem.  Look at how Google presents a million query hits.

Comment: How are the messages coming? This example does not show the real problem. Show real code.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, but for generic solution you need control that supports automatic grouping/collapsing. You have to write your own or use a third party library, both options can bring problems.

Comment: Don't put so many items in the control. Use [virtual mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes   i post real code that display message in our application .but how my Clint Message received  it is large code work perfectly .you guide me how Efficiently Scroll to last message.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the manual of `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate`.

In order to use them correctly, you should write it the following way:

```
listView1.BeginUpdate();
for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(a);
}
listView1.EndUpdate();
listView1.EnsureVisible(listView1.Items.Count - 1);
```

This should add the 10000 items and then scroll to the last one.

Between the `BeginUpdate` and the `EndUpdate` the `ListView` won't render the newly added items and thus it will not lag when adding large number of items.

After adding and rendering you then scroll to the last one.

What you did, was redundantly rendering the added item and then ensure its visibility - what again caused a rendering. This are the reasons why you application began to lag.

Comment: Adding one by one is generally slower than AddRange.

Comment: check my Real  code that i upload when we comment Scroll Lines then system perform Well . How we efficiently Scroll the list into last message.